# "call-cc" patterns in Scala?

Tags: scala, continuations

I found a good [article](http://repository.readscheme.org/ftp/papers/PLoP2001_dferguson0_1.pdf), about `call with current continuation` patterns. As I understand, they use Scheme and `undelimited continuations`. Can the patterns from the article be implemented in Scala? Is there any article about `delimited continuations` patterns in Scala ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, they absolutely can. `callCC` looks like this in Scala:

```
def callCC[R, A, B](f: (A => Cont[R, B]) => Cont[R, A]): Cont[R, A] =
  Cont(k => f(a => Cont(_ => k(a))) run k)
```

Where `Cont` is a data structure that captures a continuation:

```
case class Cont[R, A](run: (A => R) => R) {
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Cont[R, B]): Cont[R, B] =
    Cont(k => run(a => f(a) run k))
  def map[B](f: A => B): Cont[R, B] =
    Cont(k => run(a => k(f(a))))
}
```

Here's how you might use it to simulate checked exceptions:

```
def divExcpt[R](x: Int, y: Int, h: String => Cont[R, Int]): Cont[R, Int] =
  callCC[R, Int, String](ok => for {
    err <- callCC[R, String, Unit](notOK => for {
             _ <- if (y == 0) notOK("Denominator 0") else Cont[R, Unit](_(()))
             r <- ok(x / y)
           } yield r)
    r <- h(err)
  } yield r)
```

You would call this function as follows:

```
scala> divExcpt(10, 2, error) run println   
5

scala> divExcpt(10, 0, error) run println
java.lang.RuntimeException: Denominator 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Scala has an implementation of typed delimited continuations which used to be shipped with the compiler and standard library, but has been extracted to an [external module](https://github.com/scala/scala-continuations) and pretty much left to rot since then. It's a great shame, and I encourage anyone who's interested in delimited continuations to show that they care about its existence by using and contributing to it.